# Using an external file to provide labels in a standalone document

Tags: cross-referencing

Is it possible to provide the labels to a latex file from another compilation? Let's see a small example.

To be precise, I have a file with all my labels called `main.labels`:

```
$ cat main.labels
...
\newlabel{cref@sec:basics-sets}{[section][1][]3.1}
\newlabel{sec:basics-sets}{3.1}
...
```

And I was pretending to use it in my latex file as follows:

```
$ cat main.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\input{main.labels}

\begin{document}
....
In \cref{sec:basics-sets}
...
\end{document}
```

I got this using `latexmk`:

```
$ latexmk -pdf main.tex
...
Latexmk: List of undefined refs and citations:
  Reference `sec:basics-sets' on page 1 undefined on input line 9
...
```

Comment: Do you know how the reference construction works?

Comment: Well, I ran `make` in the folllowing repository https://goo.gl/fUWfqm after that I got a file main.labelsxx If you see the file `exercise_solutions` you may find something similar to what I want here.

Comment: @Werner, if I remove the labels with @ but also changing \cref by \ref, at least the compiler find the labels, but they don't appear as they suppose to be.